# Is there a means of executing code during the startup of Apache Tomcat 6.x to perform initialization routines, etc.?

Tags: java, javascript, apache, tomcat, servlets

I want to initialize a global instance of a class before my Tomcat server completes startup and begins to offer my servlets.  If this service somehow fails initialization, I'd like the entire startup sequence to fail as well (or as close to this as possible; it would be pointless for the server to be running otherwise).  What's the best way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 19):

Each web application has a ServletContext associated with it. The ServletContext object is created when the application is started and is destroyed when the application is shut down. A ServletContext has a global scope and is similar to a global variable in an application.

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/178-servletcontextlistener-example.html

complete explanation here

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/04/12/listeners.html

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks for the quick and concise help!

Comment: can you mark the answer as accepted? it will assist in getting others to respond when you ask

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do portably is to implement a servlet that initializes everything you need in its init() method (and maybe call System.exit() if it fails, i do not know if you have permission to do this in Tomcat). Then you would load it using `<load-on-startup>` in your `web.xml` to specify initialization order.

Comment: Not a good solution. All filters are initialized before all servlets. So the filters would be initialized before the initialization if the class in the question.