# How to run particular code on tomcat 24 * 7?

Tags: tomcat

The scenario is as follows,

I have one web application which will send email to the users if the particular condition match. Now I want to make this web application automate which will run 24 * 7 on tomcat server. No one is going to trigger this web application.

So I want that server itself trigger this web application and run 24 * 7. So now I am not getting an idea that where should I put this web application on tomcat so that it will run 24 * 7. If you require any other details then please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I think I am clear enough'. Sorry, but you are not.

Comment: Quartz? http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680295/is-there-a-means-of-executing-code-during-the-startup-of-apache-tomcat-6-x-to-pe

Comment: Sorry Lutz Horn.I will try to explain in more details if it is not done with Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cron at operating system level.
Or, if you have to embed it into your application, use [Quartz tasks](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).