# Run startup code on any entry point

Tags: java

Is there any way to ensure that some code is run at startup regardless of what entry point the program uses?

For example, my program has some code in a static initializer of its main entry point that checks that assertions are enabled. We had uncaught bugs a bit back because the integration test was being run without assertions enabled. The static initializer didn't catch this because it's only run when that particular class is loaded.

So is there any way to make a "program initializer": code that is always run when the program starts?

I could make some static method that each entry point has to call, but that means every single test would have to call it too (since each unit test is an entry point). That seems rather messy (easy to forget to add it, adds a lot of clutter, etc).

Is there a better solution?

Comment: This just sounds like a bug in your test suite.  Fix it and move on.  Unless you add a static initializer to literally every single class that uses assertions -- no I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: What about `@BeforeClass`  in the top level `Suite` of your tests? Or a class that is loaded no matter what the entry point is, some kind of Application context?

Comment: @markspace, the test suite did have a bug. It wasn't caught until late, however, because we were accidentally running tests with assertions disabled (Java's default). The code that ensures assertions are enabled (or crashes hard) is useful to avoid making this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like a  [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html), which is like a static initializer for your test class. It'll be run once in the very beginning before everything else.

Comment: But that only runs for the single class. That means each test class we have 135 of them, so far, needs another method. I'm not sure the clutter is worth it.

Comment: There's test suites, as @A4L mentioned, but then we'd have to create a suite for all our tests and maintain this list of tests (it's really convenient how we can currently just create a test file and Maven figures out how to run it). I'm not sure what I'm looking for is possible with vanilla Java. [Frameworks like Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680295/is-there-a-means-of-executing-code-during-the-startup-of-apache-tomcat-6-x-to-pe) seem to have such a thing, but I don't think there's an equivalent for just any Java application.

Comment: That's right about test suites. How about having a super class with @BeforeClass method and all your test classes extending this super class? Obviously involves unwanted inheritance hierarchy, but does it work for you? I haven't tried it myself, but I think test suits are anyway a better option than this one.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. I've ultimately decided not to bother implementing it (it's not a big deal -- Maven and Jenkins have assertions on by default), but it answers the question (although admittedly not the answer I was hoping for).